# React SetState Function Call not working inside if statement

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Heres my (simplified) code:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react"

const Component = () => {
    const [disabled, disableInput] = useState(false)

    useEffect(() =>  {
        console.log("Variable Got Changed")
    }, [disabled])
 
    const onSubmit = (e) => {
        // disableInput(true) // Works
        if (e.key === "Enter") {
            disableInput(true) // Does not work
            console.log("This if statement Works!")
            ...
            disableInput(false) // Does not work
        }
        // disableInput(false) // Works
    }

    return(
        <input [...] onKeyDown={onSubmit} disabled={disabled}/>
    )
}
```

My problem: Whenever I call `disbaleInput()` INSIDE the `if (e.key === "Enter")` statement, it doesn't work. If i put it before the `if-statement` (still inside the `onSubmit` function), it does work.

There is no similarly named variable or any interfering naming.

Output, `disableInput()` call **outside** of if-statement:

```
This if Statement Works
Variable got Changed // Logs later due to setState delay
```

Output, `disableInput()` call **inside** of if-statement:

```
This if Statement Works
```

I have absolutely no idea what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Try logging ``disabled`` after the variable got changed to see the exact update chain

Comment: You set it to `true` and then immediately after back  to `false`?

Comment: Wow, so I just wrote one of those questions where 1 further look wouldve made it :/ The function to wait for inside of the `if-statement` was asynchronous, so instead of waiting for its end and then setting disabled back to `false` it did both nearly instantly, not changing the variable at all. The `setState` function outside of the if statement apperantly had just enough time to update...

Comment: @Thörni yep. setState is asynchronous. Also, React does a pretty good job of batching multiple state changes together, in event Handlers and life cycle methods. So, be careful about that as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no problem with the if statement it is working and the state is also getting toggled. But the issue here is you are toggling the disabled to true and then false in the same statement. So what happens, in this case, is that useEffect does not actively “watch” for changes. When you call useEffect in your component, this is effectively queuing or scheduling an effect to maybe run, after the render is done.

After rendering finishes, useEffect will check the list of dependency values against the values from the last render and will call your effect function if any one of them has changed.

But here the value is toggled back to false again before the render could have happened and that's why the useEffect when checking for the changes it doesn't find any and that's why it doesn't console log. Try giving a little timeout to state toggling to false or comment it out for testing purposes.

I have used your code and updated [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/elastic-yalow-6mj5l?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) check it out.